# deploy compojure app that is also a CLI app

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have a Clojure app that I can use both from the command-line, and as a Compojure app.
I did that by putting a ring handler and a main function (`clojure.tools.cli`) in my leiningen `project.clj`.

`{...
:main my-app.core
:ring {:handler my-app.handler/handler }}`

The `handler` is defined `(defroutes handler ...)`.

Now if I want to run the CLI app, I can run `lein uberjar` and then `java -jar arguments`.
And I can also run the Compojure app via `lein ring server PORT`.

Now, how do I deploy the thing as a Compojure app (and not a CLI app) in a production server ? (Bonus points for explaining how `lein ring server` works.)

Note : I already use nginx if that can help, and I'm flexible on the container to be used.

Comment: Could https://github.com/boot-clj/boot be a solution ? not sure what it does yet...

Comment: Which part of deployment are you having trouble with, just the lein/project.clj syntax?  And what do you mean by "as a compojure app"?  Compojure is just a routing library, so even when you run as CLI, it's still compojure, right?  (I personally don't like `lein ring server` in dev or prod because it makes dependency injection and REPL dev difficult).

Comment: @DaxFohl by CLI I mean as a jar, then it goes to the -main entry point, which uses tools.cli. The same code used by the CLI app to do things is used by a REST API, which I run with `lein ring server 8888`, but it is the same code. I want to be able to deploy the jar and run it on port 8888.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's kind of the default template I use for new projects.  It allows you to do dependency injection into ring apps and run the app from the command line as an uberjar.  You can read more here: http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/improved-clojure-workflow

```
; handler.clj    
(defn wrap-inject-deps
  "Ring middleware that injects the dependencies into each ring request map"
  [handler deps]
  (fn [req]
    (handler (assoc req :deps deps))))

(defn create-handler
  "Similar to the default ring 'handler', but with a parameter to let you inject dependencies"
  [deps]
  (-> (routes
        api-routes
        web-routes
        (route/resources "/"))
      (kwp/wrap-keyword-params)
      (params/wrap-params)
      (json/wrap-json-params)
      (json/wrap-json-response)
      (wrap-inject-deps deps))) ; this injects dependencies

(defn start-jetty
  "Launch the Jetty instance"
  [deps]
  (let [port (Integer. (or (-> system :env :port) 5000))
        handler (create-handler deps)]
    (jetty/run-jetty handler {:port port :join? false})))


; system.clj
(defn get-env
  "Initialize configuration vars"
  []
  {:aws-access-key-id     (System/getenv "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
   :aws-secret-access-key (System/getenv "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
   :mongo-url             (System/getenv "MONGO_URL"))

(defn start
  "Launch dependencies such as DB connection and Jetty. Return these as a map, for use in REPL"
  [& [env]]
  (let [env (or env (get-env))
        deps {:env     env
              :monger  (db/init env)}
        jetty (handler/start-jetty deps)]
    (assoc deps :jetty jetty)))


; program.clj
(defn -main [& [port]]
  "App entrypoint"
  (let [env (system/get-env) ; "env" is just a map of config variables, that can be hard-coded, read from file, or whatever you want.
        env (if port (assoc env :port port) env)]
    (system/start env)))
```

You can then use leiningen profiles if you need to create multiple apps with different entrypoints from your codebase.

Comment: Well I'm not sure I can use that, since my `-main` function is used by my CLI app (parses input arguments...) and doesn't start a webserver.

Comment: @nha use leiningen profiles to specify different entrypoints.

Answer (score 1):

`lein ring server` fires up [jetty](https://eclipse.org/jetty/) to serve the web application you've built. It does this by starting the server with the options you specify in `:ring`. If you specify `LEIN_NO_DEV` in your environment, the server will run in production mode. Whether jetty is the right fit for your productions needs or not, is up to you to decide.

If you would like to run your web application on a different server, there are multiple options. One of them is running on Tomcat. Take another look at the documentation for [lein ring](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring), in particular the section on war files. Basically, you would call `lein war` or `lein uberwar` to generate a [war](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring) file. You can then e.g. drop the war file into the `webapps` directory of Tomcat.

Another option would be using [immutant](http://immutant.org/), which has substantial documentation on installation and running applications.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. Now if I was starting my server with `lein ring server 8888`, how do I make it so that tomcat/jetty serves my compojure app on port 888 ?

Comment: Well, for Jetty via lein ring, you already have your answer. For Tomcat, this is more a question about configuring Tomcat, so I would suggest you ask a new question. but it basically requires you to set the `port` variable in the `server.xml` configuration file of Tomcat.

Comment: Btw., if this was the information you're looking for, feel free to upvote / accept the answer :-)

Comment: @nha what are you asking for, more specifically?  If you want jetty to run on port 888 then you obviously do `lein ring server 888`.  But your sequence of questions seems to imply you want to be able to type `lein ring server 8888` but then have it run on port 888?  Huh?

Comment: @DaxFohl Sorry that was a typo in this particular comment. I meant that I want jetty to serve my app on port `8888`. Knowing that at noo point in my config/code I did pur the port, only when using `lein` did I specify the port. BUT I mean that without lein, on a production server (as opposed to a development server.

Comment: @nha There's nothing wrong with using `lein ring server` in production.  I did so for years until I needed a different way of doing dependency injection.

Comment: Did you bother to read the documentation of `lein-ring`? You can specify `PORT` in the environment.